# Tsung Secure Websockets Support

Tags: security, websocket, tsung

Can someone give an example xml that configures Tsung to support secure websockets (wss)?
 The default documentation doesn't say anything about whether wss is supported or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To support WSS you should specify the server type to be 'ssl':

```
<servers>
<!-- wss -->
<server host="MY_TARGET_HOST.com" port="443" type="ssl"></server>
</servers>
```